# SQL update code with 'Where exisits' not acting as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I trying to make some SQL update code that adds a line to the notes field with a where exists clause but it keeps updating every record in the table and I am not sure what I've screwed up lol. if you see my mistake in the code below and can help me out THANK YOU very much.

```
UPDATE Orders
SET notes = 'Basic Confirmation Issued by TaskCentre: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),121)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  * 
FROM  Orders INNER JOIN Order_Lines ON orders.ORDER_NUMBER = Order_Lines.ORDER_NUMBER 
WHERE Orders.ORDER_DATE >= '20150630 00:00:00' 
AND Order_Lines.PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '15CONF%%' 
AND Orders.Email > ' ')
```

Comment: The sub-select has no correlation to the main Orders? Either all rows or none will be updated as it is now.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your point about the code. I'm just not sure how I correct it :/

Comment: what database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your first query (update) has no relation with the second. So you basically are doing Update ALL my Orders if this has any result:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  Orders INNER JOIN Order_Lines ON orders.ORDER_NUMBER = Order_Lines.ORDER_NUMBER 
WHERE Orders.ORDER_DATE >= '20150630 00:00:00' 
AND Order_Lines.PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '15CONF%%' 
AND Orders.Email > ' '
```

you need to rewrite your query in a way that the first one relate with the second. Or what you can also do is, instead of using * for your select, return the ID. Then you update the clause WHERE of your first query to search for the key in the second, something like that:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET notes = 'Basic Confirmation Issued by TaskCentre: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),121)
WHERE order_number IN (SELECT  ORDER_NUMBER 
FROM  Orders INNER JOIN Order_Lines ON orders.ORDER_NUMBER = Order_Lines.ORDER_NUMBER 
WHERE Orders.ORDER_DATE >= '20150630 00:00:00' 
AND Order_Lines.PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '15CONF%%' 
AND Orders.Email > ' ')
```

You need to double check the keys, just that you can have an idea what is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

i'd go with this one:

```
UPDATE o
SET notes = 'whatever'
FROM orders o
WHERE o.ORDER_DATE >= '20150630 00:00:00' 
  AND o.Email > ' '
  AND o.ORDER_NUMBER IN 
      ( SELECT ol.ORDER_NUMBER 
        FROM Order_Lines ol 
        WHERE ol.PRODUCT_CODE LIKE '15CONF%%'
      )
```

and if you have many orders i'd add an index:

```
create index order_date on orders(order_date) 
  include ( order_number)
  where email > ' ';
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b03a/4/0)